# Java JFrame extended Not Updating Unless Re-sized

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a class, Game, that extends JFrame and I use its paint method to do all of my drawing. Whenever I add something new to be drawn (Piece)  it takes resizing the window to get the addition to be rendered. Why is that? I tried calling setVisisble(true) after drawing but that didn't fix it.

Secondly, when I use drawBottomText(g) to draw a string, it shows up great, but if I change the String that is being drawn, the old string is still shown. Resizing the window so that it covers up the 'old' string erases it.

I'm wanting paint() to work like a draw loop where the old images from last frame are wiped away and only whats drawn this iteration is what shows up. Clearly this mentality isn't accurate.

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements  MouseListener 
{
...
   public void paint (Graphics g){
       drawBottomText(g);

       board.drawBoard(g);

    }

    private void drawBottomText(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20);
        g2.setFont(font);

        g2.drawString(bottomString, 40, FRAME_HEIGHT - 20); 
    }
 ...
}

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {  
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(10);
      g2.setStroke(stroke);

      if (isAnX){
          drawX(g2);
      }
      else {
          drawO(g2);
      }
   }
```

This the is draw code that gets called by board.drawBoard(g)

```
public class Piece extends JComponent{
...
   private void drawO(Graphics2D g2){
       g2.setColor(Color.blue);
       Ellipse2D.Double ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos  - IMG_WIDTH/2 * shrinkBy, yPos - IMG_HEIGHT/2 * shrinkBy, IMG_WIDTH * shrinkBy, IMG_HEIGHT * shrinkBy);
       g2.draw(ellipse);
   }

   private void drawX(Graphics2D g2){
       g2.setColor(Color.red);
       Point2D.Double topRight = new Point2D.Double(xPos + IMG_WIDTH/2 * shrinkBy, yPos - IMG_HEIGHT/2 * shrinkBy);
       Point2D.Double bottomLeft = new Point2D.Double(xPos - IMG_WIDTH/2 * shrinkBy, yPos + IMG_HEIGHT/2 * shrinkBy);
       Point2D.Double bottomRight = new Point2D.Double(xPos + IMG_WIDTH/2 * shrinkBy, yPos + IMG_HEIGHT/2 * shrinkBy);
       Point2D.Double topLeft = new Point2D.Double(xPos - IMG_WIDTH/2 * shrinkBy, yPos - IMG_HEIGHT/2 * shrinkBy);

       Line2D.Double botRightToTopLeft = new Line2D.Double(topRight, bottomLeft);
       Line2D.Double botLeftToTopRight = new Line2D.Double(topLeft, bottomRight);
       g2.draw(botRightToTopLeft);
       g2.draw(botLeftToTopRight);

   }
...
}
```

With this method of drawing (extending JFrame and using paint()), why does the window need to be resized in order for new drawing to be rendered and why do old strings stick around?

Comment: Well, `JFrame` doesn't have a `paintComponent`, so there's something interesting and you should be calling `super.paintComponent` before performing any custom painting.  If you want to have a component update, you should be calling `repaint`

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"Well, `JFrame` doesn't have a `paintComponent`,.."*   That's why I always try to remember to use `@Override` notation.  Sure, we can discover a method is not called using a debugger, but I prefer the notation for reasons of a) documentation, and b) being warned at compile time.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean, call super.paintComponent? super.paintComponent()? I get compile errors when trying this. Components shouldn't used when doing custom painting, right? Can you explain why I should be calling repaint?

Comment: Well, then you have a problem.  As I stated in my first comment, `JFrame` doesn't have a `paintComponent`, so nothing is going to call it.  I wasn't sure if it was an issue with you slicing up your code or it was how you had actually implemented it.  You MUST call `repaint` on the component you wanted up because Swing uses a passive rendering engine, only painting those components that it thinks need to be painted.

Comment: See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and 
[Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: *"Components shouldn't used when doing custom painting, right?"*  It's typically said you should not **add** components to a custom painted panel or component, but sometimes it not only works, but is necessary (e.g. when painting a BG image for a panel containing ..other components).  But what @MadProgrammer meant was that it is also advised not to try painting to a top level container such as `JFrame` or `JApplet`, but instead doing the custom painting in a `JComponent` or `JPanel` (I prefer the latter) then **adding** that component to a top level container.  There are good ..

Comment: .. There are good reasons for doing that, including that 1) any `JComponent` is double buffered, whereas top level containers typically aren't. 2) We can draw anything that is needed, working from 0x0 as the upper left corner, without worrying about frame decorations. 3) We can suggest a preferred size for the custom painting without worrying about the frame decorations. 4) It gives us a common method to work with, where we override `paintComponent(Graphics)` instead of any others in the paint chain. ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer By saying _"you MUST call `repaint` on the component you wanted up"_  do you mean call repaint on a `Panel` that all of my drawing is done on, or call `repaint` on components on that `JPanel`? And call `repaint` when something changes? Im reading that tutorial on Custom Painting.

Comment: Call repainted on the component you want updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andrew Thompson and @MadProgrammer said in the comments, it's best to do custom painting on a JPanel and then add that JPanel to your JFrame. Do your drawing in the paintComponent() method and call repaint() in your JPanel class when you change what you're drawing. Following this method of custom painting aliviates the issues stated in the question.